# ReactJS my Search function not searching on every pages of pagination.What should I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

**My Search function only searching for products on 1 page of pagination.**

```
    // Pagination source code ==============================================================
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const [postsPerPage] = useState(6)

    const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = moviedata.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost)
    const howManyPages = Math.ceil(moviedata.length/postsPerPage)
```

```
<div className='movieslist'>
     <div className='list'>
                                    {currentPosts.filter(u=>u.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query)).map((fd, i) => {
    return <Card  img={fd.img} title={fd.title} quality={fd.quality} rating={fd.rating} price={fd.price} duration={fd.duration} year={fd.year} id={fd.id} allproduct={fd} allwishlist={fd} key={i} />
})}

    </div>

    <Pagination pages = {howManyPages} setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}/>

</div>
```

**I wanted to search the items of all pages, not just one page****but it only searches the items on one page**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1)

At first sight it seems like you are filtering `currentPosts`

If you want to search the items from all pages you should filter `moviedata`
without slicing it before filter

#### 2)

Of course it could require a bit reconstruct other parts if you need help let me know!

#### 3) How to reconstruct

If your filter is constantly applied it should solve your problem

Notice that `someString.includes('') // always returns true`
And if your query is empty you will get all of your data

```js
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const [postsPerPage] = useState(6)

    const filteredMovieData = moviedata.filter(()=>u=>u.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query)) //new

    const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = filteredMovieData.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost)
    const howManyPages = Math.ceil(filteredMovieData.length/postsPerPage)
```

Comment: Yes i guessed it whats the problem because i should filter moviedata without slicing it.But without slicing it then the pagination system will not work.I have no idea how to reconstruct.I would be glad if you can help

Comment: @EminAbdullayev check updates

Comment: thank you so much  you are awesome :) it worked the way you said i never thought of it. Very nice solution                                                                                                                       const filteredMovieData =moviedata.filter(u=>u.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query))